# Adding Angular Components over top of Canvas

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, html5-canvas

I started building out an Angular 7 HTML5 Canvas Zoom/Pan component starting from Neal Miller's project. https://github.com/Durwella/zoomable-canvas.

After a few modifications, I finally came up with something like the following. Pretend I'm making a Fire Detection Application and I want the circles to be detector device angular components that respond to SignalR updates. Could basically turn red, green, or yellow.

Does anyone know how, or have a package, to do Angular 7 component overlays over top of the canvas? Do I even need to use the canvas? Should I use absolute positioning? I'm basically just looking for some best practice guidance here I guess.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image: Image Zoom/Pan Component]

I was wondering if anyone has any insights how I may add Angular Components

Comment: Do you want allow users to resize your image? If no, it's better not to use canvas at all.

Comment: Ya, it will definitely need resized. Are you thinking absolute (x,y) position plotting of the device control components based off the canvas size? Was originally thinking that, but just curious if the community has any better suggestions.

Comment: I believe that is the best option you have so far, because as i see canvas doesn't support interactive elements over it by default. But it will be difficult for you to recalculate position of elements depending on the current scale and view field.

Comment: Thanks @Amir Arbabian for the help. I'll post with whatever I come up with.